# Are there problems associated with using multiple audioContexts with the Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, web-audio-api

I'm writing a jQuery plugin that adds some dynamic audio to the page, and it creates a Web Audio API audioContext to route the sound. Will this interfere with other Web Audio contexts that may already be on the page? Should I try to detect a context that may already be there and use that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how many AudioContexts you're talking about.  I'd suggest trying to keep one around; I seem to recall you get about three (simultaneous) before it might start causing problems.

Comment: Is there a way to get at an audioContext that may have already been generated on the page? Or should I just have the user pass the context in to an init function in my plugin if they want me to use their context.destination.

Comment: Do the latter (let the user push an audioContext to you).  You might want to keep a global one inside your code if they don't pass you one - that way, even if they don't pass one in, you'll only use one.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests you can have more than one audio context, but the nodes generated from one cannot interact with the other.  There is of course overhead for each, so you may want to test on limited memory devices such as iPhones.

Hope that helps.